# How to add values within a particular column in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

```
|NAME|ITEM |VALUE|
|john| pen | 4 |
|john| book | 7 |
|john| cup | 3 |
|Eric| pen | 9 |
|Eric| book | 8 |
|Eric| cup | 1 |
```

I want to create a field or column called "office" which equals the sum of the values of pen & book , that is, office = "pen + book"

Comment: And how do you want to behave that column? I mean should it return 11 and 17 for all rows of John and Eric respectively? That is to say three times 11 and three times 17 in your sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I  created sample data like you have given.  Now proceed this way

[image]

create a calculated field `office` with the following calculation

```
SUM(
IF [item] = "pen" OR [item] = "book" then [value] ELSE 0 END
)
```

Add this field to viz and your desired output is ready

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Anil. This should work.

Comment: Glad that it helped.  Please feel free to upvote it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for should be the Group functionality:

https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/sortgroup_groups_creating.htm

Comment: Not necessarily Fabio, I have edited the question. Please check again. & Thank you

Comment: I guess it just depends on how quick you want to implement your grouping: imagine to have 10-20 different cases to manually write in a if/case statement